# How to find if at least 3 elements within an array are within range of 50 to 99 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, range

This is given array:

```
var a = [2, 5, 8, 16, 35, 42, 55, 67, 89, 95, 102, 108, 112];
```

How to find if AT LEAST 3 elements of this array fall within range 50 to 99? If AT LEAST 3 elements within this array are within this range 50 to 99 to return true, and if less than 3 elements of this particular array a are within range 50 to 99 to return false!

Comment: Have you tried to sort it on some way? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just filter them
`a.filter(e => e >= 50 && e <= 99).length >= 3`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const atLeastThreeBetweenXAndYInArr = (x=0, y=0, arr=[]) =>
  arr.filter(e => e >= x && e <= y).length >= 3;
  
console.log( atLeastThreeBetweenXAndYInArr(50, 99, [2, 5, 8, 16, 35, 42, 55, 67, 89, 95, 102, 108, 112]) );
console.log( atLeastThreeBetweenXAndYInArr(50, 99, [2, 5, 8, 16, 35, 67, 89, 102, 108, 112]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `some` and take closure over `count`:

```js
const isMin3=arr=>arr.some((count=>o=>(o>=50 && o<=99) && ++count===3)(0));

console.log(isMin3([2, 5, 8, 16, 35, 42, 55, 67, 89, 95, 102, 108, 112]));
console.log(isMin3([1,2,65,90]));
console.log(isMin3([50,49,65,100]));
```

The advantage of `some` is, it will exit from the loop once it found its minimum match.

Comment: `&& ++count === 3` [MDN prefix increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#description)